# Eclipse style autohotkey commands

Tags: autohotkey

Is autohotkey capable of interpreting hot-keys in the style of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> I would assume a script like the following would work:

```
^+W :: ; Windows hotkeys (Ctrl+Shift+W)
   O:: Run Outlook ; Subsequent 'o' pressed => Run outlook
   E:: Run Explorer ;
return
```

From the documentation I note that these are called vertically stacked hotkeys and cause each line to perform the same action. In the case above, I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>O</kbd> will both cause outlook to be launched, whereas pressing <kbd>e</kbd> would cause explorer to be launched. What I would like is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> runs outlook and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> runs windows explorer.

Is there any way to cause a hotkey to perform context specific actions (much like in Eclipse), where I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to activate a block of specific hotkeys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example based upon what you have provided.

```
^+W::
    Input, x, L1

    if x = o
    {
        msgbox, o pressed
    }
    else if x = e
    {
        msgbox, e pressed
    }
Return
```

Source [Input](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm)